# Node.js with db2/AS400

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-midrange, db2-400

we have a project with Node.js that use the ibm_db to connect to the DB2/AS400.

The problem is that it returns the following error:

```
[SERVER] { Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968

[SERVER]

[SERVER]   errors: [],

[SERVER]   error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR',

[SERVER]   message: '[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968\r\n',

[SERVER]   state: '42968' }
```

there Is  an alternative way to connect to AS400, from node, js that does not require a license?

This is the code we use for the connection:

```
"use strict";
var models = require("../../models/index");
var express = require("express");

var db2Route = express.Router();
const ibmdb = require("ibm_db");
//import ibm_db


const opts = [
    'DRIVER={IBM DB2 CLI DRIVER}',
    'DATABASE=*****',
    'PROTOCOL=TCPIP',
    'HOSTNAME=*****',
    'PORT=446',
    'UID=*****',
    'PWD=*****',
    'DBQ=,*USRLIBL'
];




db2Route.route("/").post((req, res) => {

    ibmdb.open(opts.join(';'), (err, conn) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        conn.query("Select * from TBFR0F" ,(err, data) =>{
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else console.log(data);
            conn.close(() => console.log('done'));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access (sorry I don't know how this is set up) you can use JDBC or ODBC.  You can utilize the open source jt400 toolkit with Java (through Node.js) or you can use the node-jt400 package which wraps *SOME OF* the jt400 java library into node bindings.

```
const jt400 = require('node-jt400');
const { connect, pool, Connection, TransactionFun, BaseConnection } = jt400;
const jt400config = {
  host: 'POWER7',
  user: username,
  password: password,
  "translate binary": "true" // might be important for you...
};
const pool2 = await connect(jt400config);
const query = (pool,query) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  pool
    .query(query)
    .then((results) => res(results))
    .catch((err) => rej(err));
});
let queryResults = await query(pool2,`
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
      asdf,
      asdf2,
      CONCAT(CONCAT(asdf3,asdf4),asdf5) AS asdf6
    FROM ${library}.${table}
  ) as A 
  WHERE asdf6= '${myAsfd6}'
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this article from Aaron Bartell (who is v expert on the node.js / IBM i combo) help?

https://www.mcpressonline.com/analytics-cognitive/db2/techtip-node-js-on-linux-with-jdbc-connection-to-db2-for-i

He gives several options though none simply provides an alternative, free of charge, driver. He provides a worked example for his jdbc option.

Comment: We tried with ibm_db but as the article says, the license is needed. The web service instead is not possible because the version of AS400 is too old.
Now let's try with JDBC :)

Answer (score 0):

The ibm_db package uses Db2 Connect drivers under the covers. When connecting to IBM i, Db2 Connect requires a license as you have found.

Instead of using ibm_db, the recommended way to connect from node is with [node-odbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc) and the [IBM i Access ODBC driver](http://ibm.biz/ibmi-odbc-download). This requires no license and works across Windows, Linux, and on IBM i in PASE. We have built our [LoopBack](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/DB2-for-i-connector.html) and [Sequelize](https://github.com/markdirish/sequelize-ibmi) support on top of this package.